# From ionic popup Navigation is not working

Tags: ionic2, modalviewcontroller

I am using Ionic 2 and angular 2 for application development . I created popup using `ionic-angular` modal.I need navigation from popup to other page using ionic navigation( `push` ) method. But 'its not working on my end. The next page is loading in same component.

My code

For opening popup

```
   openModal() {

        let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(CreateModal);
        myModal.present();
    }
```

this function will open the popup. In popup html i have on click function.

```
<h2 (click)="goTonext()" data-dismiss="create-modal" >Next page</h2>
```

The click function

```
  goTonext() {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
   this.navctrl.push(NextPage
          , {
            id: res.status
          }
        );
}
```

this function will close the popup and loading the next page in same page.

It's not loading next page separately.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `this.view.dismiss()` it is closing the modal.

If you want to do some action *after dismiss*, you can do it in `onDidDismiss()` of the modal.

In your original component,

```
openModal() {

        let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(CreateModal);
        myModal.onDidDismiss(data=>{
            if(data){
            this.navctrl.push(NextPage
          , {
            id: data.status
          }
          }
        );
        });
        myModal.present();
    }
```

Send the `res` in dismiss function call.

```
this.viewCtrl.dismiss(res);
```

Comment: openModal and goTonext functions are in different components. Then  how can I  Send the res in dismiss function call.

Comment: if you send in dismiss call you can receive the data in onDidDismiss callback

Comment: thanks it's working fine. But I have one popup close in this popup This also going to next page.How can i avoid that?

Comment: I didnt understand?

Comment: I have one popup close button. I don't want to go to next page when im close the popup. need to only got to next page clicking goTonext function. if i use onDidDismiss() as per your suggestion it will navigate the page in popup close also. How can i avoid the page navigation in  popup close

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143693/discussion-between-user3541485-and-suraj).